# Decrypt HTTP payload at client

Tags: encryption, http

I was browsing this website and tried to look at the network calls from the API which retrieves the data.

[image]

As you can see, the response payload is encrypted but the browser still shows the necessary data correctly. I am assuming that there is a key that is somehow derived over at the client to decrypt the payload. Does anyone know the general mechanics of encrypting/decrypting data like this? Thanks.

EDIT: I should add that base64 decode doesn't help (or I am doing it wrong?)

Comment: Might be doing the b64 decode wrong.  Has the tell-tale "==" ending that makes me think it's base 64.

Comment: I tried all sorts of formats (utf-8/16,ISO-*). How can I be sure that I am doing it wrong? I just copy pasted the encoded payload in one of the online base64 decoders.

Comment: It's quite possible that this site uses the [web crypto api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) or a similar library to do client-side in-browser cryptography in javascript.

Comment: Why are you looking at the response to the GET and not the response to the POST?

Comment: @JohnWu How does that matter?

Comment: You said "the response payload is encrypted but the browser still shows the necessary data correctly." Usually the browser shows the data from the latest response, which in this case is the POST, not the GET. So you're comparing apples and oranges. Unless there is something about the POST request you're not telling us, e.g. if it is AJAX or something. That is why I am asking.